# How to make loop function using multiple input value to JSL in Groovy

Tags: javascript, typescript, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jsl

I'm using the below function in Jenkins Shared Library.

```
/* The below function delete uploads that exist in the server. */

 

def delete_upload(server_url,each_upload_id,authentication){

 

    def delete_upload_url  = server_url + "/api/v1/uploads/" + each_upload_id

  

    def response =  httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true,

                    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',

                    customHeaders: [[maskValue: false, name: 'id ', value: each_upload_id],

                    [maskValue: false, name: 'Authorization', value: authentication]],

                    httpMode: 'DELETE', ignoreSslErrors: true, responseHandle: 'NONE', url: delete_upload_url,

                    validResponseCodes: '100:599'

  

    if(response.status == 202){

    def result = readJSON text: """${response.content}"""

    return result['message'].toString()

    }

    else {

        throw new Exception("Incorrect upload id! Please give the correct upload id.")

    }

}
```

====================================================================================================

I'm getting below **response**,

Response Code: HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Response:
{"code":202,"message":"Delete Job for file with id 2","type":"INFO"}
Success: Status code 202 is in the accepted range: 100:599

====================================================================================================

**Purpose**: I'm using the above JSL function to delete a uploads in the web server using upload id.

**Requirement**:

I need to delete multiple uploads by using multiple upload id's (like each_upload_id in 1,2,3 etc) using this JSL delete function.

Need to pass the upload id's in loops and delete the uploads in the web server.

Any suggestions, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def idList = ["1", "2", "3"]

try {
   idList.each{ id =>
     delete_upload(server_url,id,authentication)
   }
} catch(e) {
println "Error occurred!"
}
```

Comment: Is there is a way to use the function inside JSL ? not in jenkins file

Like by putting the upload id's in a file and use the path inside the JSl and use the loop

or 

use the upload list in the JSL and use the loop

Comment: **I used the below script in the Jenkins pipeline,**
=========================================================        
       `def idList = ['8','9']
        idlist.each{ each_upload_id ->
        def delete_upload_url  = server_url + "/api/v1/uploads/" + ${each_upload_id}
       stage('delete upload') {
            delete_operations.delete_upload(server_url, each_upload_id, authentication)
        }`
**I'm getting this error**`error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: idlist for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: @Abilash I'm afraid I'm not familiar with JSL.